# Java switch between cards using jbutton

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I'm using a cardlayout and I want to make it so that the first card has a button and when clicked it will take it to card 2 which has a button that will take it back to card 1.  Here is my current code, and I've tried putting a few things in the actionPerformed method but I haven't had any success in getting it to work.  Also, I receive a syntax error on "this" on the lines with button1.addActionListener(this); and button2.addActionListener(this); which I assume is because my actionPerformed method isn't setup correctly.  Any help on getting the buttons setup would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main implements ItemListener {

JPanel cards;

public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {        
    //create cards
    JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
    button1.addActionListener(this);
    button2.addActionListener(this);
    card1.add(button1);
    card2.add(button2);

    //create panel that contains cards
    cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    cards.add(card1);
    cards.add(card2);        
    pane.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
    cl.show(cards, (String)evt.getItem());
}

public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //create and setup window
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //create and setup content pane
    Main main = new Main();
    main.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());

    //display window
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

}            

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //set look and feel
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    //turn off metal's bold fonts
    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);        

    //schedule job for the event dispatch thread creating and showing GUI        
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });     
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CardTest implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel cards;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;

    public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {
        // create cards
        JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
        button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        card1.add(button1);
        card2.add(button2);

        // create panel that contains cards
        cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        cards.add(card1, "Card 1");
        cards.add(card2, "Card 2");
        pane.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());
        cl.show(cards, (String) evt.getItem());
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        // create and setup window
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // create and setup content pane
        CardTest main = new CardTest();
        main.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());

        // display window
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() == button1) {

            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());
            cl.show(cards, "Card 2");

        } else if (ae.getSource() == button2) {

            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());
            cl.show(cards, "Card 1");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // set look and feel
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // turn off metal's bold fonts
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

        // schedule job for the event dispatch thread creating and showing GUI
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.  I am still receiving an error underneath the "this" saying: method addActionListener in class javax.swing.AbstractButton cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.awt.event.ActionListener
  found: noxia.CardTest
  reason: actual argument noxia.CardTest cannot be converted to java.awt.event.ActionListener by method invocation conversion

Comment: Change the class definition to implement _ActionListener_